# MongoDB BsonSerializer.Deserialize and F#

Tags: mongodb, f#, bson

The following snippet appears to serialize the record properly, but the deserialization sets the fields to their default values.

```
open MongoDB.Bson
open MongoDB.Bson.Serialization
open System

module BsonIssue = 

    type MyData =
        { 
            Id : ObjectId
            Time : DateTime
        }

    let serialize(data : MyData) =
        let doc = BsonDocument()
        BsonSerializer.Serialize<MyData>(new IO.BsonDocumentWriter(doc), data)
        doc

    let deserialize(doc : BsonDocument) =
        printfn "Attempting to deserialize %A" doc
        BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyData>(doc)

    let data = { Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(); Time = DateTime.Now }
    printfn "The data: %A" data
    let serialized = serialize data
    printfn "After serialization: %A" serialized
    let deserialized = deserialize serialized
    printfn "After deserialization: %A" deserialized
```

Here is an example of the output:

The data:

```
{Id = 55de887754893731fceeef58;
 Time = 8/26/2015 11:48:07 PM;}
After serialization: seq [_t=MyData; _id=55de887754893731fceeef58; Time=2015-08-27T03:48:07.836Z]
Attempting to deserialize seq [_t=MyData; _id=55de887754893731fceeef58; Time=2015-08-27T03:48:07.836Z]
After deserialization: {Id = 000000000000000000000000;
 Time = 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM;}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Add [`[<CLIMutable>]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289724.aspx) to your record:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type MyData =
    { 
        Id : ObjectId
        Time : DateTime
    }
```

FSI session:

```
> let data = { Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(); Time = DateTime.Now };;    
val data : MyData = {Id = 55dea10c4bd766216837843d;
                     Time = 27.08.2015 07:33:00;}

> let serialized = serialize data;;    
val serialized : BsonDocument

> let deserialized = deserialize serialized;;    
val deserialized : MyData = {Id = 55dea10c4bd766216837843d;
                             Time = 27.08.2015 05:33:00;}
```

Do, however, notice that the record **doesn't round-trip correctly**, because the `Time` values differ - at least on my machine. The two-hour time difference seems explainable by the fact that I'm two hours ahead of UTC currently, so my guess is that the BSON (de)serializer interprets all `DateTime` values as UTC values.

You should address this issue by using [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) instead:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type MyData =
    { 
        Id : ObjectId
        Time : DateTimeOffset
    }
```

FSI session:

```
> let data = { Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(); Time = DateTimeOffset.Now };;    
val data : MyData = {Id = 55dea3534bd766216837843f;
                     Time = 27.08.2015 07:42:43 +02:00;}

> let serialized = serialize data;;    
val serialized : BsonDocument

> let deserialized = deserialize serialized;;    
val deserialized : MyData = {Id = 55dea3534bd766216837843f;
                             Time = 27.08.2015 07:42:43 +02:00;}

> data = deserialized;;
val it : bool = true
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Funny because I chose to use DateTime just to make an example.  Good catch on that as well.